# Python - Adding to a nested list

Tags: python, list, class, nested

I created a class that is a nested list, i am now trying to add to the 0th item in the list but i dont know how to do that. so far i have

`self.[0] = list_of_num`

list_of_num = a list of numbers

i know there is something that needs to go between the "self." and the "[0]" but i dont know what. This is the code for my constructor

```
def __init__(self, num_of_lists):

        self._num_of_lists = num_of_lists
        nested_list = []
        for i in range(0,self._num_of_lists):
            nested_list.append([])
```

Comment: What about `self.nested_list[0] = list_of_num`? While also making `nested_list` as class member, of course: `self.nested_list = []` etc.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `I created a class that is a nested list`. Does you class **inherits** from list ?

Comment: J.Katzwinkle: i did that thank you. hivert: no my class did not inherit anything, look at my constructor, it created a nested list and i was trying to add to the first list inside the nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.nested_list`

```
def __init__(self, num_of_lists):
    self._num_of_lists = num_of_lists
    self.nested_list = []
    for i in range(num_of_lists):
        self.nested_list.append([])
```

and then `self.nested_list[0]=list_of_num`.

You can also eliminate the for-loop using:

```
self.nested_list.extend([] for i in range(num_of_lists))
```

Comment: thank you, i dont like that way of writing for loops, i like looking at it my way better (i am a visual person)

Comment: @user3330420 as you wish, list comprehension may speed up a bit, yet not much ;)